# Parametrization of homogenized curve

Tags: algebraic-curves, parametrization

I am trying to parametrize the following curves:

$F(z,x,y) = (x-y)^7 - z^5x^2, \quad G(z,x,y) = (x-y)^3 - zx^2$.

I first try to find a parametrization for $g = G(1,x,y)$.
I am trying to do it along the lines through the origin. Hence $y = xt$. For $g$ I get the following:

$(x-xt)^3 - x^2 = x^3(1-t)^3 - x^2 \implies x^3(1-t) = x^2 \iff x = \frac{1}{(1-t)^3} \implies y = \frac{t}{(1-t)^3}$,

which will give me the parametrization $[t_0,t_1] \mapsto [(t_1-t_0)^3 : t_0^3 :t_0^2t_1]$.

However, doing the same with $f = F(1,x,y)$ I will get $x^7(1-t) = x^2 \implies x = \frac{1}{(1-t)^{7/5}} \implies y = \frac{t}{(1-t)^{7/5}} $. But here I don't know how to get the parametrization from that. How can I proceed from there?

Comment: It's $x = \frac{1}{(t-1)^{7/5}}, y = \frac{t}{(t-1)^{7/5}}.$

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland thanks! But how can I continue from there? $[t_0,t_1] \mapsto [(t_0 - t_1) ^{7/5} : t_0^{7/5} : t_1 t_0^{2/5}]$ like this?

Comment: Maybe there's a weighted projective space solution. $(s^\frac75,t s^\frac25,(t-s)^\frac75)$ $(u^7,v^5 u^2,w^7), s=u^5,t=v^5,w^5=v^5-u^5.$ I can't seem to eliminate $w.$